# Does VSCode discourage editing installed plugins?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to contribute to a [open-source VSCode plugin](https://github.com/thegoose51/vsce-plush) for the plush language. I think I've found the error and I'm trying to test it out on my machine but when I open `%AppData%\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs\cjamesmay.plush-0.0.1` I come across a badly encoded file. I've tried searching online for what VSCode/microsoft has to say on the matter and found nothing.

This is what the file text looks like.

```
PKPK�h��%��Ƨ��A�FA�}qE�K3ș�r�Z���G��)�
(S���
��r8lկ�
```

Comment: Open an issue and ask the developers how you might contribute, https://github.com/thegoose51/vsce-plush/issues Editing the cached code is clearly a wrong approach to get started.

Comment: `PKPK` most likely means the file is a ZIP file. Copy the directory of the extension, open this new directory as a workspace in VSC and launch the extension and test it in the "new" VSC running the new version of the extension. You can also clone the repo instead of copy directory

Comment: the VSIX is a ZIP file, don't look in the cached files, look in `c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions`. The repo has no binary files (except from 2 images), it just contains a TextMate JSON description

Comment: It's definitely possible to edit installed extensions. For example I want to change hardcoded Shift+Enter for Python Interactive window, then I just change in c:\portable_installs\VSCode-win32-x64-1.47.2\data\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.109390\out\datascience-ui\notebook\interactiveWindow.js the string "{"Enter"===t.code&&t.shiftKey?r.editCellSubmit(t)" to "{"Enter"===t.code?r.editCellSubmit(t)"

Comment: @rioV8 Yes! The files are inside that folder! I imagine the best way to contribute is to initialize a git repository in the extension folder and edit it there. Thanks!